# How to remove all the beginning numeric characters in a column?

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove digits from the end of the string using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568501/how-to-remove-digits-from-the-end-of-the-string-using-sql)

If I have a sqlite table `Songs` that looks like this:

```
id  SongName    
------------------
0   midnight   
1   Another song  
2   01 midnight01  
3   01 01 midnight
4   Another record
5   1 midnight
```

Using a select or update and a REGEX expression, what would return this?:

```
id  SongName    
------------------
0   midnight   
1   Another song  
2   midnight01  
3   midnight
4   another record
5   midnight
```

I've used

select SongName from Songs where SongName REGEXP '\b^[0-9]\b'

or

select SongName from Songs where SongName REGEXP '\d'

but still not getting the results I've wanted.

Comment: @FrancisP, I edited my question to be more specific but even then, it's a far stretch to say it's a 'possible' duplicate as the answers posted in that question wouldn't help me and the question itself is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the C interface. But if you have problem in only finding suitable regex, this might work.

```
(\d+\s)+(.*)
```

It matches random amount of number-whitespace combinations, and if you return the second capture group with `$2` or `\2`, you end up with the song title.

Note: This needs a white space between the numbers you want to remove and the actual song title. It matches "01 01 some text" and "11 some text" just fine (the second capture group returns "some text"). But if you match "01 01some text" you'll end up with "01some text" (only the numbers before white space are removed).

Update. This might work. It selects only the song title. Same notes apply as above.

```
[^\d+\s]+.*
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting from the documentation:](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user
>   function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use
>   of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If a
>   application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time,
>   that function will be called in order to implement the REGEXP
>   operator.
>
> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match()
>   application-defined function. The default match() function
>   implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for
>   anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more
>   helpful logic.

So, in other words, you'll have to [use the C interface to override one or both of these operators](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).

Honestly, the best way to go about this is to restructure your data.  Either the numeric parts of the song names are useless (in which case they shouldn't be there in the first place) or not (in which case, they need to be in their own column).

Comment: I edited my question in order to reflect I want numeric characters to be removed only at the beginning of the song name.

Comment: Regardless, you'll need to override the `regex` and/or `match` operators to split this out.  Again, either the numeric part of the song name column shouldn't be there or should be in its own separate column.  Restructure your data.

Comment: @Brandon I'm also with the data restructuring option. The actual song name could begin with a number so you'll end up with an incomplete song name. If restructuring is not an option, you could insert some kind of delimiter to separate the to be removed numbers from the song title. Then it might be possible to match numbers + delimiter and remove them from the result set. (Don't really now if it's possible on the fly. At least it's possible when echoing the results on a web page.)

Comment: Jack and @ZZ-bb, I hear what you're saying but this does not help me in my case.  The data is structured automatically by banshee music player (iTunes does the same) and I'm merely trying to clean up my database.  I have no control over how things are structured.  With that in mind, help using a regex expression would be helpful and I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: You'll either have to pull apart the song name strings outside of SQLite or you'll have to use SQLite's C interface to provide a `regexp` operator, as per the documentation quoted above.